# How to archive an Azure WebApp to Storage Account

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-storage, archive

How to create a backup of webapp from Azure Powershell to a storage account?

*Note: This is a post for sharing piece of information, that I found helpful in my solution.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tools & Pre-requisites :

`Azure Powershell 4.0+`
`Windows Powershell ISE`
`Knowledge of StorageAccount ( Name, ResourceGroup Name )`
`Knowledge of WebApp for which backup is desired ( WebApp Name and ResourceGroup Name )`
`Valid & Active Azure portal / AD login credentials`

```
##########################
# Goal : To Archive WebApp desired to Storage Container
# @Param ( StorageAccountName, ContainerName, WebAppName, StorageAccountResourceGroup, AppResourceGroupName ) 

Function getArchiveStorageHandle
{
param (
         $StorageAccountName
        ,$AppBackupContainerName
        ,$webappName
        ,$WebStorgaeResourceGroupName
        ,$appRGname

        )


 ######################################################################
 #Set Active Storage to Template Storage Context


 $storage = Get-AzureRmStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName $WebStorgaeResourceGroupName -Name $StorageAccountName 
 Write-Output ( "========================== Storage Account Context Object ===========================")
 Write-Output ( $storage.Context )
 $now = Get-Date

 ######################################################################
 #Set SAS Token to get access to Container
 $SAStoken = New-AzureStorageContainerSASToken -Name $AppBackupContainerName -Context $storage.Context -Permission rwdl -StartTime $now.AddHours(-1) -ExpiryTime $now.AddMonths(1) -FullUri 
 Write-Output ( "======== Use this SAS token if prompted for manual submission Storage Account URL ==========")
 Write-Output ( $SAStoken )

 ######################################################################
 #Set BackupName and Initiate Backup process
 $backup_storage_name = $webappName + '-' + $now.DayOfYear
 $backup = New-AzureRmWebAppBackup -ResourceGroupName $appRGname -Name $webappName  -StorageAccountUrl $SAStoken  -BackupName $backup_storage_name -Verbose

 # Wait 20 seconds and check the status of the backup
 Start-Sleep 20
 $status = ($backup | Get-AzureRmWebAppBackup).BackupStatus
 Write-Host "The backup status is $status" -foreground "Yellow"

 Return $status

}
####### FN: GetArchiveStorage Ends Here #####
#############################################

$properties = @{
            'connectionName' = "AzureRunAsConnection";
            'myResourceGroupName' = "{your_webapp_Resource_group_here}"; 
            'mySubscriptionName' = "{your subscription name}"; 
            'date' = ( get-date ).ToString('MM/dd/yyyy');
            'StorageAccountName' = '{your_storage_account_name}'; 
            'AppBackupContainerName' = '{your_backup_containername_in_storage_account}'; 
            'WebStorgaeResourceGroupName' = "{your_storage_account_resource_group}";       #Pull from the JSON file
            'ResourceGroupLocation' = "East US";         #Please change this to actual if you prefer to use it.
       }
$configObject = New-Object –TypeName PSObject –Prop $properties
Write-Output $configObject


Login-AzureRmAccount
Get-AzureRmSubscription –SubscriptionName $configObject.mySubscriptionName | Select-AzureRmSubscription 
Get-AzureRmContext).Subscription
Select-AzureRMSubscription -SubscriptionName $configObject.mySubscriptionName 
$ArchiveStatus = getArchiveStorageHandle -StorageAccountName $configObject.StorageAccountName -AppBackupContainerName $configObject.AppBackupContainerName  -webappName $Resource.ResourceName -WebStorgaeResourceGroupName $configObject.WebStorgaeResourceGroupName -appRGname $configObject.myResourceGroupName

if( $ArchiveStatus -Match "Succeeded"){ 
  Write-Host "HURRAY! Archival Completed Successfully!!"
}
```

**Point to Know further:**
*Check your App Service Tier plan. This sets restriction on number of backups per day, like 20.If you got more apps and(or) frequency per day is higher, need to take account of this constraint.*

**Disclaimer:** *The intention is to share to another newbie who might find this helpful.*

Answer (score 0):

The actual script will work using the following:

```
Function getArchiveStorageHandle
{
param (
         $StorageAccountName = ""
        ,$AppBackupContainerName= ""
        ,$webappName = ""
        ,$WebStorgaeResourceGroupName= ""
        ,$appRGname= ""

        )

#Set Active Storage to Template Storage Context


$storage = Get-AzureRmStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName $WebStorgaeResourceGroupName -Name $StorageAccountName 
 Write-Output ( "========================== Storage Account Context Object ===========================")
Write-Output ( $storage.Context )
$now = Get-Date

#Set SAS Token to get access to Container
$SAStoken = New-AzureStorageContainerSASToken -Name $AppBackupContainerName -Context $storage.Context -Permission rwdl -StartTime $now.AddHours(-1) -ExpiryTime $now.AddMonths(1) -FullUri 
 Write-Output ( "======== Use this SAS token if prompted for manual submission Storage Account URL ==========")
Write-Output ( $SAStoken )

#Set BackupName and Initiate Backup process (I ain’t know why rn, but the Web App’s name had to be written manually)
$backup_storage_name = $webappName + '-' + $now.DayOfYear
$backup = New-AzureRmWebAppBackup -ResourceGroupName $appRGname -Name WEBAPPNAME  -StorageAccountUrl $SAStoken  -BackupName $backup_storage_name -Verbose

# Wait 20 seconds and check the status of the backup
Start-Sleep 20
$status = ($backup | Get-AzureRmWebAppBackup).BackupStatus
Write-Host "The backup status is $status" -foreground "Yellow"

Return $status

}

# FN: GetArchiveStorage Ends Here #####

$properties = @{
            'connectionName' = "AzureRunAsConnection";
            'myResourceGroupName' = " your web app’s resource group"; 
            'mySubscriptionName' = "your subscription name"; 
            'date' = ( get-date ).ToString('MM/dd/yyyy');
            'StorageAccountName' = 'your storage account’s name'; 
            'AppBackupContainerName' = 'your container’s name'; 
            'WebStorgaeResourceGroupName' = "your storage account’s resource group";
            'ResourceGroupLocation' = "West US or whatever zone you may have for the rg’s location";    #Please change this to actual if you prefer to use it.
       }
$configObject = New-Object –TypeName PSObject –Prop $properties
Write-Output $configObject



Get-AzureRmSubscription –SubscriptionName $configObject.mySubscriptionName | Select-AzureRmSubscription 
(Get-AzureRmContext).Subscription
Select-AzureRMSubscription -SubscriptionName $configObject.mySubscriptionName 
$ArchiveStatus = getArchiveStorageHandle -StorageAccountName $configObject.StorageAccountName -AppBackupContainerName $configObject.AppBackupContainerName  -webappName $Resource.ResourceName -WebStorgaeResourceGroupName $configObject.WebStorgaeResourceGroupName -appRGname $configObject.myResourceGroupName

if( $ArchiveStatus -Match "Succeeded"){ 
  Write-Host "HURRAY! Archival Completed Successfully!!"
}
```